# How can I link a 2010 generated DLL in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a DLL generated from Visual Studio 2010, but I need to link it to a 2008 project that needs to remain 2008 for various other reasons. Anyone run into similar trouble or have advice?

Comment: A little more info?  Managed DLL?  Unmanaged?  What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "link?"  Can't you just reference the DLL in your 2008 project?

Comment: Lots of ways that won't work.  Lots of ways it will.  There's no point in guessing at any of it without you posting the linker or runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2010 is .NET 4.0
VS2008 is .NET 3.5
So the answer for your question is NO because if the dll is making use of any of the specific .NET 4 features, it wont get executed in your 3.5 environment. Also it may happen that the assembly mapping is different in both the .NET version and that may become one of the reason for the 4.0 dll not getting executed in 3.5 env.
I am not sure, but you may look at COM Interop features. May be it can help you in achieving what you want. But it would be too messy !!

Answer (score 0):

> Dynamic-Link libraries (DLL) are an integrated part of the Windows platform from its very beginning. DLLs allow encapsulation of a piece of functionality in a standalone module with an explicit list of C functions that are available for external users. In 1980’s, when Windows DLLs were introduced to the world, the only viable option to speak to broad development audience was C language. So, naturally, Windows DLLs exposed their functionality as C functions and data. Internally, a DLL may be implemented in any language, but in order to be used from other languages and environments, a DLL interface should fall back to the lowest common denominator – the C language.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Standardized C style interface, should be ok, though that pertains only to non managed C++.